# Is the deferred/promise concept in JavaScript a new one or is it a traditional part of functional programming?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, history, promise, deferred

I really like the idea of jQuery's deferred/promise pattern or paradigm but sometimes I have trouble wrapping my aging brain around the finer points or specific implementation details.

In fact recently I've found that the deferred/promise pattern/paradigm seems to predate jQuery and is also in at least these other JavaScript libraries/frameworks:

- Deferred <sup>[github](http://documentup.com/medikoo/deferred/)</sup>
- Q <sup>[homepage](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/)</sup>
- task.js <sup>[homepage](http://taskjs.org/)</sup>
- when.js <sup>[github](https://github.com/cujojs/when)</sup>
- wire.js <sup>[github](https://github.com/cujojs/wire), [presentation](http://briancavalier.com/presentations/wirejs-2011-jsconf/)</sup>
- YUI <sup>[gallery-deferred module](http://juandopazo.github.com/yui3-gallery/src/gallery-deferred/api/modules/gallery-deferred.html)</sup>

I've probably missed some, included stuff that's really part of one of the others, and made other mistakes in that list... Please edit it to correct it or leave comments.

**Was the deferred/promise concept invented by "Q"? Was it invented with some other JavaScript library or framework? Or does it predate JavaScript completely?**

**If the whole idea has traditionally been part of functional programming, where was it first done and where can I read about the concept generally rather than these various different JavaScript implementations?**

**Or is functional programming entirely beside the point? Is the concept more related to concurrent programming than to functional programming?**

Comment: See also **[What are futures?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80447/what-are-futures)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises): **The term promise was proposed in 1976 by Daniel P. Friedman and David Wise, and Peter Hibbard called it eventual. A somewhat similar concept future was introduced in 1977 in a paper by Henry Baker and Carl Hewitt.**

See:
[Futures and promises history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises#History) on Wikipedia:

> The future and/or promise constructs were first implemented in
>   programming languages such as MultiLisp and Act 1. The use of logic
>   variables for communication in concurrent logic programming languages
>   was quite similar to futures. These started with Prolog with Freeze
>   and IC Prolog, and became a true concurrency primitive with Relational
>   Language, Concurrent Prolog, Guarded Horn Clauses (GHC), Parlog,
>   Vulcan, Janus, Mozart/Oz, Flow Java, and Alice ML. The
>   single-assignment I-var from dataflow programming languages,
>   originating in Id and included in Reppy's Concurrent ML, is much like
>   the concurrent logic variable.
>
> The promise pipelining technique (using futures to overcome latency)
>   was invented by Barbara Liskov and Liuba Shrira in 1988,[12] and
>   independently by Mark S. Miller, Dean Tribble and Rob Jellinghaus in
>   the context of Project Xanadu circa 1989.[13]
>
> The term promise was coined by Liskov and Shrira, although they
>   referred to the pipelining mechanism by the name call-stream, which is
>   now rarely used.
>   [...]

Comment: Great! I just found this independently after posting my question and have about eleven Wikipedia pages open to read. (-:

Comment: Hmm are "MultiList" and "Act 1" functional languages? I'm guessing this concept is more related to concurrency than to functional languages like I originally asked...

Comment: @hippietrail: it's [**MultiLisp**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiLisp) and yes, it's a functional programming language (a dialect of Lisp/Scheme). Act 1 was an experimental programming language for constructing [actor systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) - see [this paper](ftp://publications.ai.mit.edu/ai-publications/pdf/AIM-625.pdf) (pdf) from 1981 by Henry Lieberman.

Comment: Actually, the concept of promises _as we know_ them is more Liskov and Shrira and less Baker and Hewitt although their contribution is sound.

Answer (score 6):

I think  in JavaScript deferred/promise concept first appeared in [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/Deferred.html) (inspired by Python's [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html)) then in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

The notable moment is work of CommonJS group which put a lot effort to "standarize" promises for JavaScript, see [A](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A), [B](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/B) and [D](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/D) proposals, on that basis Kris Kowal's [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) (I guess currently most popular implementation) evolved.

[Deferred](http://documentup.com/medikoo/deferred) (I'm the author) is later implementation, it was initially inspired by [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), its goal is to make promises feel natural in JavaScript, and also to make transition from Node.js callback style easy.

But yes as @rsp wrote, promises are much older concept than JavaScript itself :)

Comment: `Deferred` was in `MochiKit` before `Dojo`. Dojo added it after Mochikit, then `jQuery` added it after Dojo but jQuery's implementation behavior is slightly different.